Is there a way to know which jobs are scheduled to execute?
Hello my programming friend :)
My problem is exactly the title, in details, we are talking about an insanely amount of jobs existing in a pair of servers, some of them are just copies and doesn't execute. How can I find which ones are working in order to avoid check one by one?
Thanks in advance for your time and answers :)
Greetings and blessings
I tried checking which ones has an output on the column "Elapsed time" on DataStage Director and track its "job control", but I'm looking for other idea :)

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
